# Transition duration with tailwind css

Tags: tailwind-css

Is there a class for the transition duration with tailwind CSS? 
For example, is there a way to add transition duration on this example div?

```
<div class=”text-black hover:text-red”>test</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update 2020:
CSS Transition and CSS Transform is now available.

--> [Tailwind CSS v1.2.0](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/releases/tag/v1.2.0)

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit: [tailwindcss v1.2.0 added transitions in 2020](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/releases/tag/v1.2.0)

---

There are currently no transition utilities in standard tailwindcss (there is an open issue on [github](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/14) from 2017). However, transition utilities can be enabled through plugins. You should look at benface's plugin [tailwindcss-transitions](https://github.com/benface/tailwindcss-transitions).

```
npm install tailwindcss-transitions
```